# Objective C get JSON from PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I'm making some app, where the app call PHP to pass the JSON file.

In my PHP code I have a result of JSON like this `{"files":[{"name":"sharing-config.txt","date":"28-11-2014-11-59-59"},{"name":"2.jpg","date":"28-11-2014-14-25-35"}]}`

Now I want call the JSON result to my objc function and return it as **`NSArray`**, is anybody can help me?

Many thank for your help :)

Sorry for my bad English.

UPDATE

Bellow is my PHP Code

```
$directory  = '../download/sponsors';

$arrayFiles     = array();

if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {


$i = 1 ;

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

    if($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){

        if (file_exists($directory  . "/" .$entry)) {

            $fileList       = array("name" => $entry, "date" => date ("d-m-Y-H-i-s", filemtime($directory . "/" .$entry)));
            $arrayFiles[]   = $fileList;

        }

    }
}

closedir($handle);
}


$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->files = $arrayFiles;

echo json_encode($obj);
```

My ObjC code

```
-(void)getPHPdata {
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appserver.com/applications/appUpdate.php"]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSString *receivedDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"This1: %@", receivedData);
    NSLog(@"This2: %@", receivedDataString);
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[receivedData setLength:0];
NSLog(@"This3: %@", receivedData);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the new data to receivedData.
// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
[receivedData appendData:data];

filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // Get the return value from server

connectionSuccess = YES;


NSLog(@"This4: %@", [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]);
NSLog(@"This5: %@", receivedData);
}
```

Here is the LOG i got from xCode

`2014-11-28 14:35:51.905 balisfinestvillas[17577:9635538] This4: {"files":[{"name":"sharingconfig.txt","date":"28112014115959"},{"name":"2.jpg","date":"28112014142535"}]}`

Cheers :)

Comment: show your code plz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `JSon` response is started with `NSDictionary` not the `NSArray`

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

 NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options: kNilOptions error:nil];

  NSMutableArray *finalresult=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  // allocating the array

    NSArray *responseArr=[jsonDict objectForKey@"files"];

    for (NSDictionary *tmp in responseArr) {

      NSMutableDictionary  *itemshowdetails=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        [itemshowdetails setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
        [itemshowdetails setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"date"] forKey:@"date"];

         [finalresult addObject:itemshowdetails];

    }

   }
```

**retrieve**

this method is used for where u want to access your data , customize your self

```
 for (int i=0;i<[finalresult count];i++)
{
 NSLog(@"%@",[[finalresult objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: `self. self.finalresult`? Not clear why you have used two times `self`.

Comment: oh sry sry , just wait, I updated my answer

Comment: @Kampai -- y u given the download vote, can u explain me what i made the mistake

Comment: As per your repo - You have to explain what you did. You haven't explain where to put this for loop. Also you have not answer as per OP's need.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik please let me know, where I can pass my PHP url on your code, thanks.

Comment: your coding is fine , now I updated my answer ,plz add this in your code

Comment: @Kampai -- check that my updated answer

Comment: See OP use `didReceiveData ` method to get data from PHP web service. And you have use different method.

Comment: Hi @Anbu.Karthik your code is work like a charm thanks :)

Comment: @Kampai -- do u used this concept in before, how many type we can access the response in request method

Comment: What my concern is - As you have enough reputation that you can explain in details that which can deliver enough understanding for OP. Any ways as per this issue OP was satisfied now, so vote from me too.

Comment: @Kampai -- tanx kampi, onwards I follow this in every answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Happy to hear this, explanation will gives you up vote too. Welcome.